# Hide points in ChartJS LineGraph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Originally I set the fill color for each point to be completely transparent. If I run my mouse over the graph, the points pop up. I want to hide all points so that the line graph is smooth.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting point's radius property in configuration options as follows:

```
var chartConfig = {
            type: 'line',
            options: {
                elements: {
                    point:{
                        radius: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Tooltips for the points will also gone off.

Comment: this config is global, but I got a chart which included 3 lines chart, I just wanna disable one of them

Comment: @fifth you can set the `pointRadius` property on each individual dataset object.  See @Alexander's answer below.

Answer (score 144):

You can set the [`pointRadius`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) to zero.

```
var myChart = new Chart(
    ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [...]
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [...],
                pointRadius: 0,  # <<< Here.
              }
            ]
        },
        options: {}
    })
```

Comment: I've added "borderWidth: 1" and "pointRadius: 0.5" because I also needed a fine line and tiny dots to hover over them.

Comment: I needed to add `pointHitRadius: 0` as well to disable tooltips.

Comment: @throrin19 What did not work? It is fully documented per the link above.

Comment: Oups sorry. I think I have disabled my click. My problem was with vue-chartjs. Options have not sync correctly with chartJS

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but I wanted to keep the hover option active.
There is my solution:

```
const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets:[{
                label: 'Température',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: tempE,
                pointStyle: 'rect',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            elements:{
                point:{
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    radius: 10,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

What actually worked for me to remove the points and keep the tooltip with the version 4 was to set the pointStyle property to false. Is the last option in the list provided in the [official docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-styles).

The code could be something like this:

```js
const chart = new Chart('canvas-id', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        label: 'Some label',
        data: [...],
        pointStyle: false
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer! The only problem is that TS doesn't like the pointstyle being a boolean, but I just suppress that

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `radius: 0` to hide the dot, additionally you can turn up the `hitRadius: 10` which sets the radius outside of the dot which you can hover to make the popover show. This allows you to hide the dot while still making the point easy to hover and open the tooltip.

```js
var chartConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
        hitRadius: 10,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More documentation on `elements` in chart.js can be found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html